# Distance between variables in an array

Tags: java, arrays, distance

I am new to Java and I am trying get distances between the variables in the stations field and it doesn't seem to work.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
double[] stations = {10,20,30};{
for(int i=0;i<stations.length-2;i++){
    double distance=stations[i+1] + stations[i];
}
```

Comment: it seems that you have to `substract` rather than `add`

Comment: Please post the expected (required) result of your code.

Comment: Distance is usually a difference of values.

Comment: In addition to @nachokk's comment also you are initializing the variable distance again and again for each iteration so it would never be correct

Comment: What **exactly** does your array represent?

Comment: I've amended the subtract sign, that was a mistake. I am trying to print the distance between 10 and 20, 20 and 30.

Comment: @Doris Glancing again, you probably want `i < stations.length - 1`, not `i < stations.length - 2`. (on top of what Rupesh said)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `substract` rather than `add` to calculate distance between each one. So you need two for loops to get all combinations.

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

            int i =0;
            int j=0;
            double[] stations = {10,20,30};
            for(i=0;i<stations.length;i++){
                for(j=i+1;j<stations.length;j++){
                 System.out.println("distance between station "+i+" and station "+j+" is "+ (stations[j] - stations[i]));   
                }               
            }
}
```

Output:

```
distance between station 0 and station 1 is 10.0
distance between station 0 and station 2 is 20.0
distance between station 1 and station 2 is 10.0
```